# Understanding some Ubuntu shell commands

Tags: command-line, scripts

I need to understand how a script that was given to me works. There are some if conditions and commands and syntaxes I have no idea what they do and I've tried Googling them but had no luck.

1. So what does `[ -z String ]` do?

   For example this appears in the script `[ -z "$(which ssh)" ]`
   Also is `$(which ssh)` a string or a variable?
2. What does `~/.filename` mean? I know that `./filename` is used to execute files sometimes and that `./` its a pointer to the directory itself, but what is the `~/.`?
3. What does `[ -e  filename ]` do?
4. What does `[ ! -d ~/.ssh ]` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find more about `[` by typing `man [` into the terminal. This is a test construct for use after `if`, etc. Hence,

```
   -z STRING
          the length of STRING is zero
   -e FILE
          FILE exists
   ! EXPRESSION
          EXPRESSION is false
   -d FILE
          FILE exists and is a directory
```

1) `[ -z "$(which ssh)" ]` means test if `"$(which ssh)"` is a zero-length string. `$(...)` means to execute the `...` part first. If you run `which ssh` in a terminal, you'll see that it will produce the path to the `shh` executable, if it exists. Hence, if this exists, then the string will not be zero-length, and the test will fail.

2) `~` is a shortcut for your home directory, usually located at `/home/your_user_name`. `[ -e filename ]` means test if this file exists, and return true if it does.

3) `[ ! -d ~/.ssh ]` means test if `~/.ssh` (probably `/home/your_user_name/.ssh`) exists and is a directory, and if it is **not**, then return true.

---

==EDIT==

You should try and sort out the man problem, because it'll really advance your bash knowledge. If `man [` doesn't work, try `man test` instead. (`test` is a synonym for `[...]`.) If not, here is an [online version](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html).

```
   -w FILE
          FILE exists and write permission is granted
```

I actually think you might have it the wrong way around. It should be

```
[ -w "$1" ]
```

not

```
[ "$1" -w ]
```

Comment: ive tried using man [ but with no resutls. also googling it. What about [ "$1" -w ] what does -w do to the archive that has route $1?

Comment: I'll answer in the answer, so I can format.